# Renderer after a filter, rows no longer highlighted

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, rowfilter

I have the following renderer and tooltip within my method

```
tableR = new JTable(modelR)
{
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        Font myFont = new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,10);
        Font myFont1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,10);
        if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
            if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
                String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 11);
                c.setBackground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
                c.setForeground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
                c.setFont("0.0".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);
            }
        }  

        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
        String tip = null;
        java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
        int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
        int colIndex = columnAtPoint(p);
        int realColumnIndex = convertColumnIndexToModel(colIndex);

        if (realColumnIndex != 20) { //Sport column
            tip = " " + getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex);
            //tip = super.getToolTipText(e);
        }
        return tip;
    }
};
```

This gets applied after each refresh of the method which occurs every 10 seconds.

I also have a filter listener method on the table this takes the form:

```
 private void filter2method() {

    filterR.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
newFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    newFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
newFilter();
    }

    private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter <DefaultTableModel, Object>rf =null;
   try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterR.getText(),2);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);


    } }

    );
    }
```

However upon filtering my table the renderer no longer highlights the right rows in red ..ie the ones that are 0.0

How do I deal with this? Do I need to remove the renderer and then reapply it?
Do I need to incorporate my renderer method into the filter method.. help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The renderer reports view-indices, not model-indices. You are using a view-index to index the model in the statement `String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 11);`

The if-statement where you set the colors should read:

```
int rowModelId = convertRowIndexToModel( row );
if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
    if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
        String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId , 11);
        c.setBackground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
        c.setForeground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
        c.setFont("0.0".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);
     }
}
```

You could also have written it to get the cell value using [`JTable.getValueAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) (this method takes view-indexes) to avoid having to use the `convertRowIndexToModel` method as follows:

```
if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
    if (tableR.getColumnCount() >= 0) {
        String type = (String) getValueAt(row, 11);
        c.setBackground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
        c.setForeground("0.0".equals(type) ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK);
        c.setFont("0.0".equals(type) ? myFont1: myFont);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ TT the renderer works fine however the problem is that after i filter the table as a document listener, the highlight no longer highlights the correct row because the table now has less rows. I need the highlight to highlight the new filtered table

Comment: @MrAssistance Let me first ask, did you apply both versions of what I answered, and did you see the same behaviour in both instances?

Comment: @ TT I havent no, because i dont think the problem lies here - the problem is that after i type into the filter it filters the table model and then highlighted rows no longer highlight the correct rows. I think because the highlight is fixed on the current table..

Comment: @ TT Hey guess what i applied your method and it works!! why??

Comment: @MrAssistance It's a glaring error in your code that I highlighted. If you don't want to take advice from pros, then why ask questions on StackOverflow???

Comment: @MrAssistance Because *"The renderer reports view-indices, not model-indices. You are using a view-index to index the model in the statement"* ... it's the first thing I said =)

Comment: deffo a pro!! I just never thought that is where the error lies and embarrassingly i glossed over it...thats the last time i do that..thanks for your amazing help. I wasnt in the same plain of thought :(

Comment: @MrAssistance You are welcome. Do me a favor, and accept my answer by checking the checkmark on the top left of my answer =)

Comment: I understand now - the way i was setting it was in a view only perspective and not setting it to the model